# Selenium test log

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium for testing purpose - Java Webdriver 4.

I need the store results/status(pass/fail) of my Selenium test in a database or can get it any other way. I just need to check if a test case has passed or failed and log result in a Defect tracking tool via its API. 
Please who have ever come across this scenario please guide me. I cant find a way to get the test results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write an own rule by extending [TestWatcher](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) and override `failed` and `succeeded`.